# Fix botched package-install

Tags: package, package-repositories

Today there was [a bug](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa/issues/3487) in the package recipe for magit in MELPA. The bug has been fixed but the new package has not yet been built. In the meantime, how can I either

1. revert to a previous, working version of the package?
2. manually install the recipe from MELPA's git repo?

Also, how can I avoid being stuck without a working package in future?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically why I disagree with those who choose not to put packages under version control with the rest of their Emacs config.

If you want to guarantee that your config is always complete and in working order -- or able to be reverted to previous states if that is not the case -- you want to put all of it under version control.

Comment: n.b. the magit web site has documentation on installing it in various different ways, including from its own git repository, so consult that for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've cooperated with Quelpa's author in creating it, so this post is most certainly biased.

You can use [Quelpa](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa) to build anything packagable with a MELPA recipe to your liking.  This can be used both to simply rebuild a package from its sources or to build an earlier snapshot that's been known to work for you.